# This method must return a result of type int[][]

Tags: java, matriz, syntax-error

Estou tentando fazer esta função de multiplicação de matrizes mas está dando erro.
Mostra que o erro está **mult(int linha, int coluna, int linha2, int coluna2, int[][] matriz, int[][] matriz2)** e diz 'This method must return a result of type int[][]'

```
public static int[][] mult(int linha, int coluna, int linha2, int coluna2, int[][] matriz, int[][] matriz2) {
    
        if(matriz[0].length == matriz2.length){
            int[][] matrizR = new int[linha][coluna2];

            for(int i = 0; i < linha; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < coluna2; j++)
                    for(int k = 0; k < linha2; k++)
                    matrizR[i][j] = matriz[i][k] * matriz2[k][j];
            }
        return matrizR;
        }
    }
```

Comment: O que a função deveria retornar caso não entre no if? null? Adicione um retorno para o caso de não entrar no if que vai funcionar.

Comment: Ainda não. Acho que ele para antes de chegar no if, pois o problema está no nome da função e as variáveis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todos os caminhos do seu código precisam ter um retorno. Você especificou o retorno dentro do IF, mas caso não entre no IF a função segue até o final sem nenhum comando de retorno.

Há 2 formas simples de solucionar isso:

1. Faz a checagem do numero de linhas e colunas antes de chamar a função.
2. Mantém a checagem na função e retorna null caso não seja possível efetuar a multiplicação.

   ```
    public static int[][] mult(int linha, int coluna, int linha2, int coluna2, int[][] matriz, int[][] matriz2) {

       if(matriz[0].length == matriz2.length){
           int[][] matrizR = new int[linha][coluna2];

           for(int i = 0; i < linha; i++){
               for(int j = 0; j < coluna2; j++)
                   for(int k = 0; k < linha2; k++)
                      matrizR[i][j] = matriz[i][k] * matriz2[k][j];
           }
           return matrizR;
        }
       else 
           return null;
    }
   ```

A forma que você tá calculando a multiplicação tá incorreta, dá uma conferida.